# Insert Table of Figures Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have made an index of tables on my Word document. For that I used "Insert Table of Figures".

Here is an example of one caption of my table:

Table 3.1: Caption example.

On index items the titles are exactly equal to the caption. I want to know how can I put my index items like this (removing the word "Table" and the ":"):

3.1 Caption example

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

When you insert your table of figures, you can deselect "Include label and number", however that will also remove the number.

If you really need to show number, but don't show "table", then you need to do it manually.